# Prove $|X| = |\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$|

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Let $X$ be a set of sequences $s \in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ with elements $0,1$ such that in $s$ three $1$ do not reoccur immediately. Prove, that $|X| = |\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$|.**

My attempt:

> $|X| \leq |\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$

It is obvious since $\{0,1\} \leq \mathbb{N}$

> $|X| \geq |\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$

Let $f$ be a injective function, which transforms $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ into a sequence, in which a number of $0$'s represents each number from $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, and numbers are separated by $1$'s. For example {1,2,3,...} = {01001000...}

**Let $X$ be a set of sequences of natural numbers $s \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ such that $s$ is nondecreasing Prove, that $|X| = |\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$|.**

My attempt:

> $|X| \leq |\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$

It is obvious since $s \in \{0,1\}$.

> $|X| \geq |\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$

Let $g$ be a injective function, $g(s)(n)=$ a sum of all previous elements (or a sum of all previous elements $+1$ if $g$ were to be an increasing function.

Example: $\{1,2,3,4,5...\} = \{1,2,4,7,11...\}$

Can you tell me if my solutions are sufficient and, more importantly, correct?

Comment: The first one is fine; the second is unintellligible to me. If you're defining $g$, then you need to PROVE it's injective (if, in fact, you need that). But I can't even make sense of the definition.

Comment: why should s be non-decreasing?  $\{1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1...\}$ =$\{0,1,0,0,2,2,...\}$ is not decreasing.  And you haven't said anything about no three consecutive 1s.  i.e. there are no three consecutive 0s.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language so I have some problems with getting my ideas across (or maybe my solution has no sence). Anyway, I provided an example to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is fine as long as you don't think $0 \in \Bbb N$.  If you do, a series of three $0$s in the string will generate a series of three $1$s in your element of $X$.  This is easy to patch, just make the run of zeros one more that the number in the string from $\Bbb {N^N}$.  In your "It is obvious" it would be better to say $|\{0,1\}| \le |\Bbb N|$ or (if $0 \in \Bbb N$) $\{0,1\} \subset \Bbb N$

For the second, your "It is obvious" should be $X \subset \Bbb{N^N}$.  Your construction is fine as long as $0 \not \in \Bbb N$ and again that is easy to patch with a $+1$.  The example should use an arrow instead of an equal sign.